# How to use omnifaces CDN resource handler with versioned resources?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

How to use omnifaces CDNResourceHandler with versioned resources?

**Original url:**

`javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.0`

**Desired url:**

`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js`

How to map this to a specific url, omitting the version query parameter?

**Mapping:**

Using following mapping appends the version query parameter to the final url resulting in 404 HTTP error.

`primefaces:jquery/jquery.js=//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js`

**Results in:**

`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js&v=5.0`

**System:**

Glassfish 4
Mojarra 2.24
Primefaces 5.0
Rewrite 2.11

Comment: Looks like PrimeFaces is doing that. Will investigate later.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it with PrimeFaces 5.0 which is provided as "Community Download" [here](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads). Which PrimeFaces 5.0 version exactly are you using?

Comment: I am using the same version 5.0 from community download. I am also using rewrite from http://ocpsoft.org/. Will check it out tomorrow if this can be an issue.

Comment: Removing rewrite has no effect. The version query parameter is appended to the final url. Edited Questions with more system informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced it. This will happen when the PrimeFaces `PrimeResourceHandler` is initialized *after* OmniFaces `CDNResourceHandler`.

If you've declared the `CDNResourceHandler` inside `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml`, then this is quite unexpected and likely a bug in GlassFish4.

But if you've declared the `CDNResourceHandler` inside `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` of a JAR which you in turn placed inside `/WEB-INF/lib`, then this can indeed happen if GlassFish initializes that JAR before the PrimeFaces JAR. In order to solve the problem, you need to explicitly declare your JAR's `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` to be initialized after the PrimeFaces one by adding the following entry to your JAR's `/META-INF/faces-config.xml`:

```
<ordering>
    <after>
        <name>primefaces</name>
    </after>
</ordering>
```

Alternatively, move the `CDNResourceHandler` declaration to webapp's `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml`.

Comment: I declared `CDNResourceHandler` inside `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` of shared jar. This is the problem. Defining `PrimeResourceHandler` before `CDNResourceHandler` within the shared `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` is not solving the problem for me. The solution is to declare `CDNResourceHandler` inside main application `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml`. No need to declare `PrimeResourceHandler` anyway. If you edit your answer i will mark it as correct. You think this is a GF4 bug?